# SSIS: how to send an email if a stored procedure returns a certain value

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I would like to be able to run a SQL task that runs a stored proc.  The proc returns 0 or 1.  If it returns 1 then email.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what version of SQL you are using (Server, Server Express, 2005, 2008, etc, ?) Also, if the mail functions are already configured in your SQL server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the execution result from the stored procedure in a variable. Add a send mail task and edit the [precedent constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141261.aspx) expression to evaluate the result of the variable which then conditionally executes the send mail task.